# Can you read android phone "Most Played Songs" list

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am developing an android application related to music. It would be a nice feature to have to be able to see what songs (if any) are the users most played songs on their android device.
Or the songs they starred or made a favorite list(s). Is this possible? where is this information stored? I have looked at MediaStore and nothing really stands out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be application specific. Stared or played songs would only be tracked by independent applications. Some users might use Google Play Music, others Pandora, File Managers, etc. So short answer no. If you want to target a specific application then you should specify.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of accessing the data owned by an application directly, thats why i mentioned MediaStore and tagged my question with android-contentprovider. Does MediaStore give access to "Starred" tracks?